# Reusing cached instances

Tags: java, caching

I have an application that uses a data structure `Point`. Let's say that overall there are 50 distinct instances of `Point` (meaning `p1.equals(p2)` == false). However during calculation loads of new instances are created, that are actually the same as already instantiated objects.

As these instances are stored this has a heavy impact on memory consumption:
50 distinct `Point`s are represented by 500'000 instances of `Point`. In the data structure there is nothing that would prevent the reuse of already present instances. For that reason I created a cache:

```
HashMap<Point, Point> pointCache = new HashMap<>();
```

So I can check if the point is present and add it if it is not. This kind of cache however seems like a bit of overkill, as the key and the value are essentially the same.

Furthermore I already have a map present:

```
HashMap<Point, Boolean> flag = new HashMap<>();
```

What I am curious about is: Is there a map like data structure that I could use for `flag` that would allow the retrieval of the key? If not is there any other data structure that I could use for the cache that would be more like a set and would allow easy checking and retrieval?

**EDIT:** For completeness, the `Point` class I am using is `javafx.geometry.Point2D` and therefore nothing that I can change.

Comment: See Guava's [Interner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interner.html) and [Interners](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html).

Comment: Looks promising, thanks @BenManes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume, for the sake of this answer, that the uniqueness of a `Point` is determined by two int coordinates, x and y (you can change that easily to fit the actual parameters that determine your `Point`'s uniqueness).

You don't want to create a `Point` instance in order to determine if that `Point` already exists in some `HashSet` or `HashMap`. That defeats the purpose of avoiding creation of multiple instances (though using a `HashMap` or `HashSet` would prevent you from keeping all those duplicate instances, and the GC will release them soon, so it may be enough to solve the memory consumption issue).

I'm suggesting that you have a static `Point getPoint(int x,int y)` method in your `Point` class. That method would check inside a static internal `HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,Point>>` whether those x,y coordinates already have a corresponding `Point` instance and return that instance. If an instance doesn't exist, it will be created and added to the `HashMap`.

This is similar to what `Integer.valueOf(int)` does for small integers - it returns a cached `Integer` instance instead of creating a new one.

Comment: In general this seems like a good solution, unfortunately my `Point` class is `javafx.geometry.Point2D` and I therefore cannot change it. Would it be worth the overhead to supply my own `Point` class?

Comment: @hotzst You can still use that `Point2D` class without having to wrap it. Just create a `Point2DFactory` class that would maintain the cache and be used for obtaining those `Point2D` instances.

Comment: `Integer`s are only cached for small values (0-127, if I remember correctly). And `Double`s (which would be needed for `Point2D`, are not cached at all. So unless the coordinates are always integers in the range 0-127, you are still creating two (short-lived) objects for each hash map lookup. Using `Point2D` objects as the key seems clearer (or simply using a `HashSet`) seems clearer.

Comment: @Hoopje The IntegerCache was just an example for caching a small number of instances. The OP expects 50 distinct Point instances, so the cache in this case would be smaller than IntegerCache.

Answer (score 2):

Your map is entirely reasonable. You could create your own wrapper class if you wanted to, but I'd probably stick with the map for the moment. If `Set<E>` exposed an operation of "get the existing entry which is equal to this one" then you could use that, but a) it doesn't and b) `HashSet` is built on `HashMap` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Better you could use a `HashSet` instead of `HashMap` which would save you from storing different `boolean` against each points. Although `Set` would internally use `HashMap` but in place of value, it would use the same `Object` reference which would be better than storing odd 50 `boolean` values which doesn't makes sense and is useless in your case.

You could do a lookup like:

```
 if (set.contains(point)) {
    ...
 }
```